# How do I migrate the content of a SQL table?

Tags: 7, migrations

I have a sql table which contains Visitor name, Afiliation, Start date and End date.

I have created a content type named "Visitors" which contains title (i.e Visitor name), Affiliation (Text field), Start and end date (Date field)

How can I migrate my sql records from tables to populate this content. Please share the online resource link and other material which can help me to achieve this objective.

I am using Drupal 7.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it using the [Feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) module.

> - Import or aggregate data as nodes, users, taxonomy terms or simple database records.
> - Import or aggregate CSV files
> - Create nodes, users, taxonomy terms or simple database records from import
> - Extensible to import any other kind of content
> - Granular mapping of input elements to Drupal content elements
> - Exportable configurations
> - Batched import for large files

#### Reference

- [Importing data from a comma separated value (CSV) file into one multi-value field.](https://www.drupal.org/node/2285537)
- [Importing content with the feeds module](http://www.pixelite.co.nz/article/importing-content-feeds-module/)